# Typescript hinting for inference of recursive types?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a library that has a recursive function:

```
const generateTreeNode = () => {
  return {
    value: 1,
    // ...other properties...
    next: generateTreeNode
  };
}
```

Without any additional information, typescript will fail to infer the recursion:

```
declare const generateTreeNode: () => {
    value: number;
    next: any;
};
```

I know I can get the compiler to correctly identify the type if I specify it:

```
type TGenerateTreeNode = () => {
  value: number,
  next: TGenerateTreeNode
};

const generateTreeNode: TGenerateTreeNode = () => {
  return {
    value: 1,
    // ...other properties...
    next: generateTreeNode
  };
}
```

What I'm wondering is if there is anyway to hint to the compiler where the type definition recurses without having to specify the other (non-recursive) properties (such as `value`). Ideally, something like:

```
type TGenerateTreeNode<TOther extends {[key: string]: any}> = () => {
  next: TGenerateTreeNode<TOther>
} & TOther;

// This errors without a defintion for the generic on TGenerateTreeNode
const generateTreeNode: TGenerateTreeNode = () => {
  return {
    value: 1,
    // ...other properties...
    next: generateTreeNode
  };
}
```